# Change user nicename without sanitize

Tags: filters, sanitization, username

How to remove sanitize from `edit_user_profile` action?

I have a possibility to change user_nicename with the following code:

```
function ex_insert_nicename_input( $user ) {
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    // Find the proper class, try to be future proof
    $regex = '/<tr(.*)class="(.*)\buser-user-login-wrap\b(.*)"(.*)>([\s\S]*?)<\/tr>/';

    // HTML code of the table row
    $nicename_row = sprintf(
        '<tr class="user-user-nicename-wrap"><th><label for="user_nicename">%1$s</label></th><td><input type="text" name="user_nicename" id="user_nicename" value="%2$s" class="regular-text" />' . "\n" . '<span class="description">%3$s</span></td></tr>',
        esc_html__( 'Name' ),
        esc_attr( $user->user_nicename ),
        esc_html__( 'Unique' )
    );

    // Insert the row in the content
    echo preg_replace( $regex, '\0' . $nicename_row, $content );
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'ex_insert_nicename_input' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'ex_insert_nicename_input' );
```

If I enter "Ab" and updeate user info it will save it as "ab". Is it possible to filter this process and sanitize text, but without transform letters from uppercase to lowercase?

[image]
[image]

The only thing I need to do is to remove or change this line `$user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user_nicename );` in `user.php`. But I don't know how to do it correct, without changind core files...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is being converted to lowercase by filter `sanitize_title`

```
// in wp-includes/default-filters.php
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );

// it means => calling sanitize_title_with_dashes() in wp-includes/formatting.php
```

Here is explanation to what can do, recommended and not recommended method

#### Not Recommended

You may remove this filter but **not recommmended**
Because this filter is for converting title with dashes, you may go to see the source code for reference.

```
// in theme's php
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10 );
```

---

#### Recommended

add filter 'sanitize_title' with custom checking without affecting the original features

```
// load later than the original filters
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'ws365107_custom_sanitize_title', 15, 3 );
function ws365107_custom_sanitize_title( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {

    // may make use of the $_POST object data to check if it adding 

    // for original design $context = 'save' could distinguish, however, theme developers usually don't place this $context argument, so it render the argument useless
    if( $context === 'save' ) {     
    }

    // check by action if action = createuser from user-new.php, avoid affecting other situation
    // please adjust if use in other situations
    if( isset( $_REQUEST ) && isset($_REQUEST['action']) ) {
        // custom logic in checking user name using $raw_title
        $title = $raw_title;

        return $title;
    }

    // return original title for other situations
    return $title;
}
```

Extended reading:

- [remove_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/)
- [sanitize_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/)

Comment: Great job! Thank's for and example of usage!